# I can't connect to mqtt broker with nodemcu until DNS Retry 2 times

Tags: lua, dns, nodemcu

I can't connect to mqtt broker "hivemq" until the DNS Retry 2 times.
The problem is that Dns retries after the code have been all executed, so I can't publish any message despite it is connected to broker. 
I've tried as wheel to set DNS server but it didn't solved anything.
I am using ESPlorer ide on mac.
Thank you for your help, Luca

```
ssid = "my ssid"
pswd = "my pswd"

wifi.setmode(wifi.STATION)
print("connecting to wifi")


wifi.sta.config(ssid,pswd) 
tmr.delay(5000000)
print(wifi.sta.getip())


net.dns.setdnsserver("8.8.8.8", 0)--sets google first dns server--
net.dns.setdnsserver("8.8.8.8")  --equal to above
net.dns.setdnsserver("8.8.4.4", 1)  --sets google second dns server
--net.dns.setdnsserver("208.67.222.222", 0)--sets opendns first dns server
--net.dns.setdnsserver("208.67.222.222")  --equal to 
--net.dns.setdnsserver("208.67.220.220", 1) --sets opendns second dns server

--net.dns.getdnsserver(0) --gets first dns server
--net.dns.getdnsserver() --equal to above
--net.dns.getdnsserver(1)  --gets second dns server
net.dns.resolve("www.google.com", function (socket,ip)

if ip == nil then print("error: DNS fail!") else print(ip) end
end )

tmr.delay(5000000)



m=mqtt.Client("nodemcu", 1200, "username", "password")
print("hey")
connected = false



   m:connect("broker.hivemq.com", function(client) print("connected to broker") connected = true end, function(client,reason) print("reason:") print(reason) end)
   tmr.delay(5000000)

  if connected==true then print("connected is true") else print("connected is false") end


tmr.delay(10000000)

m:publish("/topic", "hello", 0, function(client) print("message published")end)
```

This is what I get from nodemcu dev kit 1.0:

```html
192.168.1.64 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.254
hey
connected is false
init.lua:47: not connected
stack traceback:
 [C]: in function 'publish'
 init.lua:47: in main chunk
 [C]: in function 'dofile'
 stdin:1: in main chunk
> DNS retry 1!
DNS retry 2!
connected to broker
```

Comment: I suggest you learn how to deal with the event-driven nature of NodeMCU, using [`tmr.delay`](http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/modules/tmr/#tmrdelay) is a no-go for pretty much every use case. Start with a proper `init.lua` which initializes WiFi: http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/upload/#initlua

Comment: Only publish once your client is connected by calling `m:publish` in the connected-callback.